# Update image via WP REST API

Tags: uploads, rest-api, media-library

So I wonder if its possible to update images in the media library via the REST AP? Ive seen [a github issue](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/2824) back in 2016 where its mentioned this its not supported in the REST API. Is this still the case? Cause in the REST API docs I do find an update media method via ID...but somehow I cant get it to work in my R syntax.

I have a code which upload images automatically (and works perfecty :) but I want to have them refreshed daily. And according to the [REST API doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/#update-a-media-item)s it should be doable via: POST /wp/v2/media/id

Any thoughts?